# How to paste Cyrillic letters to word document (phpword)?

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii1.x

I have following code in my PHP file:

```
                        $PHPWord = new PHPWord();
                        header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
                        $template = $PHPWord->loadTemplate('protected/controllers/template.docx');
                        $template->setValue('Value2', '102');
                        $template->setValue('Value3', 'ИНН');
```

Here 'ИНН' is in Cyrillic. When I paste value `'Value3'`, it is pasting these `ÐÐÐ` symbols to the word document. I need to insert `ИНН` word to the word document. How can I do it?

Comment: What version of PHPWord are you using? What does it have to do with Yii? If it does, which version? Do you use layouts when running this code? How do you save it and to which format?

Comment: I suggest give more details and also add "phpword" tag to the post.

Answer (score 0):

Latest version (v0.13.0) produces the needed behavior with this code only. The php file was utf-8 encoded.

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

$templateProcessor = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor('template.docx');
$templateProcessor->setValue('Value2', '102');
$templateProcessor->setValue('Value3', 'ИНН');
$templateProcessor->saveAs('test_utf8.docx');
```

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehrzY.jpg) is the screenshot of the result.